# Convert Date to String with format "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"

Tags: ios, swift, date

My Swift code:

```
let format = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = format
dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone.current
let date = Date()
print(dateFormatter.string(from: date))
```

Format of result always such as "2018-04-12T13:33:18+0700"
Can set result format like "2018-09-19T17:00:00Z"

Comment: `Z` is the time zone?  You want it converted to "ZULU"?

Comment: What about removing the last "Z" in the format? `let format = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"`?

Comment: Set the timezone to `TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)` and use "X" instead of "Z" in the format.

Comment: Note that you can play around date formats here, very useful: http://nsdateformatter.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want that specific format, you have to set the timezone to UTC

```
dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)
```

and use the date format `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssX"` (`X` instead of `Z`)

---

An easier way is `ISO8601DateFormatter`

```
let dateFormatter = ISO8601DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)
let date = Date()
print(dateFormatter.string(from: date))
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong date format, `Z` would appear as `'Z'`:

> **Date Format:** `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"`

Where `Z` represents the GMT/UTC timezone.

`Z` = Zulu time => GMT+0

**Correction:**

Update your date format as:

```
let format = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")
let date = Date()

print("This is UTC Date -> \(date)")

let dateFormat = DateFormatter()
dateFormat.dateFormat = "h:mm a"
let currentTime = dateFormat.string(from: date)

print("After Formatted -> \(currentTime)")
```